# How do I get rid of these warnings?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, warnings

This is really several questions, but anyway...

I'm working with a big project in XCode, relatively recently ported from MetroWorks (Yes, really) and there's a bunch of warnings that I want to get rid of. Every so often an IMPORTANT warning comes up, but I never look at them because there's too many garbage ones. So, if I can either figure out how to get XCode to stop giving the warning, or actually fix the problem, that would be great. Here are the warnings:

- It claims that `<map.h>` is antiquated.
  However, when I replace it with `<map>`
  my files don't compile. Evidently,
  there's something in map.h that isn't
  in map...
- this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
  This is a large number being compared to an unsigned long. I have even cast it, with no effect.
- enumeral mismatch in conditional expression: `<anonymous enum>` vs `<anonymous enum>`
  This appears to be from a ?: operator. Possibly that the then and else branches don't evaluate to the same type? Except that in at least one case, it's 
  `(matchVp == NULL ? noErr : dupFNErr)`

  And since those are both of type OSErr, which is mac defined... I'm not sure what's up. It also seems to come up when I have other pairs of mac constants...
- multi-character character constant

  This one is obvious. The problem is that I actually NEED multi-character     constants...
- -fwritable-strings not compatible with literal CF/NSString

  I unchecked the "Strings are Read-Only" box in both the project and target settings... and it seems to have had no effect...

Comment: Some parts of your question appear to be missing.  E.g. "It claims that is antiquated." What is? Replace what with what?

Comment: No, not "but anyway." If you have several questions, then please just post several questions. It allows the answers to be more specific, and it allows the question title to be more meaningful and therefore easier for others to find later.

Comment: What @Rob said. Please ask each question separately, so that others might be able to find them and benefit from the answers as well.

Comment: What @jalf said.  Also, you're just running through questions without sufficient detail.  You have five questions there, and so all you can say about `<map>` is "my files don't compile".  Split up your questions, and then you'll feel better about expanding them into something we can potentially answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'll split it up next time. I thought of this as 5 instances of one question rather than 5 questions...

Comment: and sorry, I didn't notice that my cut/pastes didn't quite work with the <...> thanks for the edits.

Comment: Treating these all as a single question, the only answer is to disable warnings. But then the cure is worse than the disease. Each warning really needs to be considered separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items in `<map.h>` are in the global namespace while items in `<map>` are in the std namespace. Most likely you were just referring directly to the global versions and when you switched to `<map>` you were no longer seeing them because they moved to `std::`. In source files add a `using namespace std` to move on quickly. In headers you'll need to qualify uses of map-related items with `std::`.

I think you'll need to qualify the literal constant value with a trailing UL so it knows the correct type of the literal.

Most likely the enums are in two separate OS defined anonymous enums. You can static_cast them to quiet the warning.

No idea on the multi-byte chars.

Can you disable -fwritable-strings? Can you refactor the code that needs to modify constant strings?

Comment: I need the writable strings mainly because the alternative is to go through and make a whole lot of char * into const char*... I'll get around to that one of these days...

Answer (score 3):

> "multi-character character constant"
>   This one is obvious. The problem is that I actually NEED multi-character constants...

Compile with `-Wno-multichar` -- add it to Other Warning Flags, and leave the Four Character Literals warning switched off.

Of course, whether this legacy code's multi-character character constants actually **mean** the same thing as they did under Metrowerks probably on a different architecture... is an open question.

Comment: Multi-character constants for MacOS (pre-MacOSX) compilers tended to just stick the characters into an array, so `'dht1'` would be similar to `char foo[4] = {'d','h','t','1'};`, so they'd be useful for MacOS file metadata.  I don't offhand know how the gcc in XCode handles multichar constants, but the MacOSX file structure is straight Unix, and doesn't use the four-character file and application IDs.

Comment: @David: Uh, no.  Those compilers interpreted them as integers of the "appropriate" size in the "obvious" way, leaving you open to endianness excitement.  On a sensible big-endian host, the layout in memory would be the same as your array; in the modern all-the-world's-Intel regime, not so much.  //  Your point about modern MacOSX not using multi-character character constants so much if at all is right, but the OP doesn't say what he's using them for...

Comment: The endianness excitement didn't really happen, as MacOS was dead by the time Apple moved to Intel, and the 68000 and PPC were both (unless I'm remembering way wrong) big-endian.  It was pretty much necessary for all Mac compilers to do the same thing, obvious or not.  I don't know what the OP was using them for, but file metadata was by far the biggest use back then.

Comment: @David: The point is that __this OP__ is about to encounter the excitement if he just disables this warning without looking at what all these multi-character character constants are doing in his code!

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I don't seem to be experiencing endian issues. Possibly because I'm flipping them twice... I'm just comparing the 4 char code to the code of the resource in the rsrc file... if both are backwards, then no big deal...

Answer (score 1):

That decimal constant is written like `3111222333UL`?

Comment: Even better: UINT32_C(3111222333)

Comment: @nall: Thanks for mentioning that. I was not aware of it, but it makes a lot of sense. Will use it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that at least as of Xcode 3.2.4 you can make the warning go away by using a number of characters in the constant that is the correct length for the type.

For example I had a constant that was only 3 chars long 'TT2' and it was giving me the multi-character character constant error. Adding 0's to the constant made the errors go away, like so: '\0TT2'.